# Polynomial with a root modulo every prime but not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I recently came across the following fact from 
[this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/16834/454) list of counterexamples:

> There are no polynomials of degree $< 5$ that have a root modulo every prime but no root in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Furthermore, one such example is given: $(x^2+31)(x^3+x+1)$ but I have not been able to prove that this does has that property above. How can such polynomials be generated and can we identify a family of them?

Comment: Do you know Galois theory of finite fields? If $p$ is an odd prime and $f(x)$ is a monic irreducible of degree $3$ in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ then the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbf F_p$ has degree $3$, so the Galois group must be $A_3$ and thus the *discriminant of* $f(x)$ *is a square in* $\mathbf F_p$. This implies if $F(x)$ is a monic irreducible cubic in $\mathbf Z[x]$ with discriminant $D$ that is not a square in $\mathbf Z$ then $F(x)(x^2-D)$ has a root mod $p$ for every prime number $p$. For example, $x^3+x+1$ has discriminant $-31$, which is your example.

Comment: related: [is there an irreducible polynomial that has a root modulo every prime?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/471014/)

Comment: I have added an answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608919/is-it-true-that-if-fx-has-a-linear-factor-over-mathbbf-p-for-every-prim/1825623#1825623 that explains why your example has a root modulo every prime.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want an easy example of polynomial that has root modulo every prime but not in $\mathbb Q$ — just take e.g.
$$
(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)
$$
(it has this property since the product of two non-squares mod p is a square mod p).

One more interesting example is $x^8-16$ (standard proof uses quadratic reciprocity).

As for possibility of complete description of all such polynomials — I'm skeptical.

Comment: Thanks. Also why can't we find another polynomial of degree $< 5$? KCd gave some sort of an answer in the comments but it did not quite answer the question.

Comment: Actually, I don't know (beside [quadratic case](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33675/)). You might want to ask a separate question.