# A number is square in F_p for every prime p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving that an integer is the $n$ th power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/proving-that-an-integer-is-the-n-th-power)

Let $n$ be a natural number, if $n$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$, is $n$ also a square in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: The "duplicate" mentioned has a much stronger hypothesis: that $n$ is a square mod $k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})/\mathbb{Q}.$ As the polynomial $x^2 - n$ factors in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p,$ we have $p$ splits in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})}$ for almost all primes $p$. It follows by the Chebotarev density theorem, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n}) = \mathbb{Q}.$ Hence, $n$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}.$

Note that $n$ only needed to be square mod $p$ for some set of primes of density greater than $1/2$ in order to conclude $n$ was a square in $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Oops. I didn't see the tag. Let me see if I can think of another proof.