# existence of a prime $p$ for which $a$ is a primitive root

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is known that every prime $p$ has a primitive root modulo $p$. Is every number $a$ which is not a perfect square a primitive root modulo $p$ for some prime $p$? If it is a square, we already have $a^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod $p$)}$, so the condition on not being a square is necessary. However, I'm not sure what would suggest that not being a perfect square is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't easy to show.  The general problem (for nth powers rather than just squares) is discussed here: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/proving-that-an-integer-is-the-n-th-power].

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the full answer is not yet known. Certainly the (much) more difficult problem of whether every number other than $-1$ and the perfect squares is a primitive root of *infinitely* many primes is not fully settled. This is [Artin's Conjecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots)

However, there are many partial results towards Artin's Conjecture. for example, Hooley proved Artin's Conjecture, assuming an (unproved) version of the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis.