# does there exist a prime such that...

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $n>1$ be an non square positive integer (you can have it prime, if you wish), does there exist a prime $p>2$ such that $n$ generates the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_p$? It sounds true, but I could not find an immediate proof for that... maybe using some reciprocity law? Not sure.

Comment: Have you tried a few examples? Does it work when p=3?

Comment: If n is odd let p=2. Not sure about even n.

Comment: p=3, n=7 fails since 7 is congruent to 1 modulo 3 so it does not generate. But anyway the question is the other way round: you should fix n and find p

Comment: edited with p>2, sorry.

Comment: You may [find this useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778454/does-every-prime-2-have-a-primitive-root-that-is-a-prime) as a start. Every prime $\gt 2$ does have a prime primitive root.  There is a lot more known, including size estimates.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422201

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general question in a strong form is the contents of [Artin's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots):

> Every integer which is neither a perfect square nor equal to $−1$ is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes.

This remains unproved.