# Common generator of units in finite prime fields

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

It is well known that the unit group of a finite field is cyclic. What can we say about the generators?

Specifically I am interested in the following question:
Suppose we fix a positive integer $a$, how many primes $p$ are there such that $a$ generates the unit group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$? Are there infinitely many?

Comment: @MorganRodgers The question is how many *primes* $p$ are there such that a fixed integer $a\mod p$ generates $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, not how many $a$-s for a fixed prime $p$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an open problem.

There is [a famous conjecture due to Artin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) giving the density of the set of those primes $p$ such that a non-square natural number $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Positive density, of course, implies that $a$ is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes $p$.

Note that if $a=b^\ell$ for some integer $b$ and prime $\ell$, then $a$ is automatically not a primitive root modulo a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv1\pmod\ell$. This lowers the chances for such an $a$ to be a primitive root, and the conjectured density is adjusted accordingly. An extreme case is when $a$ is a perfect square, for then this obstruction applies to all primes, and therefore perfect squares are not interesting for the purposes of this question.

---

There is an analogue of Artin's conjecture for the polynomial rings $R=\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. In that case the question is whether the coset of a given non-square polynomial $f(x)$ is a primitive element of the finite field $R/\langle p(x)\rangle$ for infinitely many irreducible monic polynomials $p(x)\in R$. That version (together with a density formula) was proven by Bilharz.