# If all primes larger than $n$ divide a polynomial, then is the polynomial reducible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> You are given a non-linear integer polynomial $P$ and an integer $n$ such that any prime above $n$ divides $P(x)$ for some integer $x$. Is it necessary that the polynomial is reducible?

I was trying to solve the problem "show that any non-square integer $a$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo infinitely many primes" and noticed that if we show that the polynomial $x^2-a$ cannot have only finitely many primes **not** dividing it, we are done. This then generalized to the above statement which I am posing as a question.

It seems intuitively obvious that the above statement is true. Searching for a counterexample has not helped.

Is there an elementary way of tackling this problem?

Thanks in advance.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/proving-that-an-integer-is-the-n-th-power). The answer by Eric Schneider is a gem.

Comment: Isn't this true for $P(x) = x$? Maybe you meant "non-linear polynomial"?

Comment: @Arthur, yes I was actually looking for non-linear polynomials. Edited,Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chebotarev density theorem](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Chebotarev.pdf).If you read carefully,excersise  7.1 is exactly what you want.
An elementary argument could be found I suppose but the answer you seek is in this paper.
Nice question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently, this is out of my depth, but I am sure countless others will find this useful.