# Explanation about integer being $l$-th power modulo every prime

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $l$ be a prime number and let $x$ be an integer which is an $l$-th power modulo every prime. The claim is that $x$ is the $l$-th power of some integer.

I've read the following proof, but I don't understand it:

"Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(x^{1/l})$ and its Galois closure $L / \mathbb Q$. Then for each prime $p$ which is unramified
in $L$, there is a prime ideal $P$ in $K$ above $p$ such that $f(P/p)=1$.
So the corresponding Frobenius fixes some $l$-th root of $x$.
By Cebotarev theorem, $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$
has no element of degree $l$ and so it fixes some $l$-th root of $x$, which lies in $\mathbb{Q}$."

My questions:

1. Why does the Frobenius element $Frob_{Q/p} \in Gal(L/\mathbb Q)$ fix some $l$-th root of $x$? Here $Q$ is a prime of $L$ above $P$.
2. Why does $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ have no element of degree $l$ ? A priori, we don't know whether $T^l - x$ is irreducible or not over $\Bbb Z$.
3. Why does it imply that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ fix some $l$-th root of $x$?

I know the statement of Cebotarev theorem but don't know how to apply it here. I would like some details about this, please.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/proving-that-an-integer-is-the-n-th-power