# Natural numbers $n$, $k$ are given such that for any prime $p$ there exists an integer $a$ satisfying the condition $p\mid a^k-n$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, fermat-numbers

> Natural numbers $n$, $k$ are given such that for any prime $p$ there exists an integer $a$ satisfying the condition $p\mid a^k-n$. Decide whether $n$ must necessarily be the $k$-th power of a natural number.

The only thing that occurred to me is that it reminds me of a small Fermat theorem.

Comment: See also [this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6976/242) where it is assumed that $n$ is $k$'th power mod all $m$ (vs. all prime $m)$. This has a [very simple pretty proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1847906/242)

Comment: @Bill Dobuque but $p \neq x^2$, in your proof

Comment: Yes, the linked question is another form of this question (cf. "this *form*"). It is helpful to link together closely related questions.

Comment: @Bill Dobuque I don't understand your proof, could you explained it for me on this problem, please.

Comment: It's best to ask under the proof. Please say precisely which inference is not clear.

Comment: @Bill Dobuque Could you please write similar answer to this problem like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/an-integer-is-a-nth-power-if-that-holds-true-for-all-moduli/1847906#1847906 Please. So I can close it.

Comment: @Bill Dobuque So now I understand your proof to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/an-integer-is-a-nth-power-if-that-holds-true-for-all-moduli/1847906#1847906 but I dont know how transformate or change to my problem.

Comment: It doesn't immediately apply here due to the weaker hypothesis here.

Comment: So what should I do.