# Show that $16$ is a perfect $8$th power modulo $p$ for any prime number $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that $16$ is a $8th$ power $\mod{}$ $p$ for any prime number $p$.

I have no idea how to approach this.

I tried,

$$a^8\equiv16\pmod{p}$$

$$(a^4+4)(a^4-4)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

$$a^4 \equiv \pm4\pmod{p}$$

$$a^4 \equiv 2,p-2\pmod{p}$$

But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/showing-x8-equiv-16-pmodp-is-solvable-for-all-primes-p